# Создание второго потока для отслеживания нажатия клавиши в цикле while

Tags: python, while, break

Нужно прервать цикл по нажатию кнопки Esc. Как реализовать максимально просто ? Желательно вторым потоком. не могу найти инфу в тырнэте.

```
while True:
    print('1')
```

Comment: Пакет keyboard там есть и примеры остановки по нажатию. Останется только обернуть в поток. https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

Comment: спасибо, сделал уже с помощью from pynput import keyboard